# Internet Explorer 11 Group Policy Disable Find Files via F3 within the browser not working

Tags: windows-7, windows-registry, internet-explorer, group-policy, windows-server-2012-r2

The policy, located at User Configuration\Administrative Templates\Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Search: Disable Find Files via F3 within the browser, does not work for IE11. This policy was designed only for IE5 and IE6

I've also attempted adding a registry entry:

```
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Internet Explorer\Restrictions\NoFindFiles
Type: DWORD
Data: 1
This has not worked either to disable it.
```

The environment is composed of a 2012r2 Active Directory system with Windows 7 and above workstations.

Does anyone have any solutions to implement this for the latest version of IE?

Comment: What behavior exactly are you trying to prevent.  The group policy you mention doesn't apply to IE11.

Comment: Prevent the find page from coming up with using the F3 key and CTRL+F keys.

I stated in the question that policy doesn't apply to IE11, I need an alternative.

Comment: It appears the feature was removed in its entirety.  Can I ask the reason you are attempting to disable the search bar?  I understand you need an alternative, but there isn't one, and I was repeating a fact.  Please be kind.

Comment: The environment this will be on will be locked down in it's entirely and our Information Security Office has asked to disable this for a set of users.

Comment: You also going to disable "CTRL+A","CTRL+V" into a notepad and then hitting "CTRL F"?  You can even hit "CTRL F" in IE11, and even if you did disable the search bar, i am suspect it would disable "CTRL F"

Comment: Yes, all the CTRL keyboard shortcuts need to be disabled as well.

Comment: Sounds like you should be using Kiosk mode in that case, and specifically, third-party software to achieve your goal.  Because you won't get it with the built-in features of Windows.

Comment: So far, everything I needed to lock down is complete with built-in features. Except this one item. This is the last piece that needs to be completed.